# I tried a Programmable-Hide-Unhide-Columns-from-Dropdown-Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want that everytime you choose an item from a dropdown menu in A2, it will hide every column and unhide only the pertinents columns for that item.

It's a project where my employees doesn't know Google App script, so I have to try make programmation easy for them and directly on the sheet.

I already tried to make my own code, but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea ?

```
function onEdit() {
  var Sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  var Menu = Sh.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var LastCol = Sh.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  if (Sh.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 1 && (Sh.getActiveCell().getRow() == 1)) {
    if (Menu == "Agent 1") {
      var FindRow = Sh.getRange("B:B").createTextFinder("Agent 1").findNext().getRow()
      var Rg = Sh.getRange(FindRow, 3, 1, LastCol - 2)
      var AllemptyArr = Rg.createTextFinder("").findAll();
      for (var i = 0; i < AllemptyArr.length; i++) {
        Sh.hideColumn(AllemptyArr[i].getColumn());
      };
      var AllxArr = Rg.createTextFinder("x").findAll();
      for (var j = 0; j < AllxArr.length; j++) {
        Sh.unhideColumn(AllxArr[j].getColumn());
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what the sheet look like:

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail of `it doesn't work.`? 2. Can I ask you about the relationship between `I want that everytime you choose an item from a dropdown menu in A2, it will hide every column and unhide only the pertinents columns for that item.` and your sample image? I couldn't understand about your goal.

Comment: Sure.
1. When I run the script by choosing "Agent 1" in the dropdown menu in A2,
it should hide every columns from C to H and unhide every columns where there is an "x" in the row "Agent 1" in the table below. But, unfortunately, nothing happen.

2. "Agent 1" is an example of the list of the dropdown list. His pertinent columns are where there is a cell with an "x" in the row "Agent 1" in the table below.

I hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `it should hide every columns from C to H and unhide every columns where there is an "x" in the row "Agent 1" in the table below.`, is it required to hide all columns and show the specific columns? For example, is the direction that only the specific columns are shown different from your goal? And in your situation, I think it is required to know the range of below the cell "B18". Because from your sample image, we cannot understand about the number of "Agent" for `the table below`. And also, can you update your question by including the detail information?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to do it my way. As long that only pertinent column appear and the other doesn't depends of what appear in the dropdown menu and where the "x" are in the "table below".

Comment: The "table below" isn't a table below B18. It's the table B12:H18.
When I choose "Agent 1" from the dropdown menu, it first search for the range in the table B12:H18, in that case, it would be C16:H16. Then, it look every cell in that range that are empty and hide their column. Then, it look every cell in the range that have an "x" and unhide their column.

Comment: In the dropdown menu, there is "Agent 1", "Agent 2", "Agent 3". So, if I choose "Agent 2", it will do all the same, but the range would be C17:H17. For "Agent 3", the range would be C18:H18.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to show columns of "Column 1" to "Column 6" which has `x` in the cell value.

  - "Column 1" to "Column 6" are the column "C" to "H" in the actual range of the sheet.
- You want to hide columns of "Column 1" to "Column 6" which has the empty cell.
- You want to check the row when the value of the cell "A2" is the same with one of cells "B16:B18".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, this if statement of `if (Sh.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 1 && (Sh.getActiveCell().getRow() == 1)) {}`, the cell "A1" is checked. By this, when the drop down list of the cell "A2" is changed, the script in the if statement is not run. I think that this is the reason of your issue of `nothing happen`.
- And in your script, from `if (Menu == "Agent 1") {}`, only when `Menu` is `Agent 1`, the script is run. In order to achieve your goal, `Agent 1`, `Agent 2` and `Agent 3` are required to be checked.
- In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve values from "B16:H18".
  2. Retrieve the row when the value of cell "A2" is the same with the value of cells "B16:B18".
  3. Show and hide rows from the retrieved row.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var Sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  var Menu = Sh.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var LastCol = Sh.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  if(Sh.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 1 && (Sh.getActiveCell().getRow() == 2)) {
    // 1. Retrieve values from "B16:H18".
    var values = Sh.getRange("B16:H18").getValues();
    
    // 2. Retrieve the row when the value of cell "A2" is the same with the value of cells "B16:B18".
    var selected = values.filter(([b]) => b == Menu);
    
    // 3. Show and hide rows from the retrieved row.
    if (selected.length > 0) {
      var columnOffset = 2;
      selected[0].splice(0, 1);
      selected[0].forEach((e, i) => Sh[e == "x" ? "showColumns" : "hideColumns"](i + 1 + columnOffset));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I think that in your case, the event object of OnEdit event trigger can be used. But I thought that you might want to run the script using the script editor, custom menu and a button. So in this modification, I didn't use the event object.

#### References:

- [showColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)

Comment: Yes. I just try and it work. Thank you. I just start learning Google App Script and I learnt with you. Thank you for that. I confess that I don't fully understand yet the class .filter .splice and .forEach, but I will read about it right now. That's a great website.

Comment: @Manuel Pelletier Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.